# Get the last value of partition group in Hive query, but with additional requirements

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Say I've got 3 columns in a table: id, flag, time. Flag can only be one of the three: A1, A2, B.

```
ID  flag    time
1   A1  2016-01-01
1   A2  2016-01-02
1   B   2016-01-03
1   B   2016-01-04
2   A1  2016-01-02
2   B   2016-01-03
2   A2  2016-01-04
2   B   2016-01-05
```

The data has been sorted by time for each ID. Now I'd like to get, for each ID, when the flag equals B, the last non-B flag, e.g.:

```
1   B   2016-01-03  A2  2016-01-02
1   B   2016-01-04  A2  2016-01-02
2   B   2016-01-03  A1  2016-01-02
2   B   2016-01-05  A2  2016-01-04
```

Is this even possible in a Hive query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  id
       ,flag
       ,time
       ,A.flag as A_flag
       ,A.time as A_time

from   (select  id
               ,flag
               ,time

               ,max
                (
                    case 
                        when flag <> 'B' 
                        then named_struct ('time',time,'flag',flag) 
                    end
                ) over
                (   
                    partition by    id 
                    order by        time 
                    rows            unbounded preceding
                )  as A

        from    t
        ) t

where   flag = 'B'
;
```

---

```
+----+------+------------+--------+------------+
| id | flag |    time    | a_flag |   a_time   |
+----+------+------------+--------+------------+
|  1 | B    | 2016-01-03 | A2     | 2016-01-02 |
|  1 | B    | 2016-01-04 | A2     | 2016-01-02 |
|  2 | B    | 2016-01-03 | A1     | 2016-01-02 |
|  2 | B    | 2016-01-05 | A2     | 2016-01-04 |
+----+------+------------+--------+------------+
```

---

P.s.

- I would recommend not to use what might be a reserved word (`time`) as column name.
- I would recommend not to use undescriptive names such as `time` for date column.

Comment: I'll appreciate it if someone could edit this.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I get some null for the last two cols. Maybe add ` and not isnull(ns)` at the end?

Comment: The solution was verified. Aliases changes were made for clarity. The original solution worked 'as is'. See updated answer.

Comment: Any progress with the NULL issue?

Comment: Yeah that's some edge situation where there are no A flag in front of B. Your answer is right.

Comment: One more quesion: How does Hive compare named_struct? I googled and it says named_struct is compared by the first value, e.g. in your example it would be `flag`. Should it be `named_struct('time', time, 'flag', flag)`? The result doesn't change thought, but in theory it should compare time, and get the last flag for the max time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138172/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-dofine).

Answer (score 1):

Use `max` window function to get the running maximum time for non B flags. Then `join` this result to the original table to get the flag information for the corresponding max time (before flag B for a given id).

```
SELECT X.*,
       T.FLAG
FROM
 (SELECT T.*,
  MAX(CASE WHEN FLAG<>'B' THEN TIME END) OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIME) AS MAX_TIME_BEFORE_B
  FROM T
 ) X
JOIN T ON T.ID=X.ID AND T.TIME=X.MAX_TIME_BEFORE_B
WHERE X.FLAG='B'
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/YNEQW29444)

Comment: Works for sql and Hiveql. Thanks !